# How do I filter data in a DataSet before making an Excel file out of it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, email

I am sending mail with an `attachment` to the respective user by the below code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cls_Email_Sql ce = new Cls_Email_Sql();

        List<string> ls_attach = new List<string>();
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlConn))
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();

                DataTable tb_RA = ds.Tables[0];
                DataTable tb_User = ds.Tables[1];

                string strcolorHead = "#C0C0C0";
                string strcolorDet = "#C0C0C0";

                var groups = tb_RA.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("RAName"));  // grouping the RA column

                foreach (var group in groups)   // RA Table
                {
                    sbodyMail = "Dear " + group.Key + ", <br /><br />  " +

                    "As per the details available in the system, below are the summary  "+
                    "of number of documents lying with your reportees for more than five days. "+
                    "This is for your information and necessary action ";

                    sbodyMail += "<table style='width: 400px;font-size:12px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' " +
                                "border='0'><tr><td style='width: 100%;'></b><td></tr></table> " +

                                "<table style='width: 470px;font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height: 53px' border='1'><tr> " +
                                "<td style='width: 30px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>SR No</strong></td> " +
                                    "<td style='width: 300px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>UserName</strong></td> " +
                                "<td style='width: 120px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>Document type</strong></td> " +
                                    "<td style='width: 20px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong><div>No. of docs working </div><div> for more than five days</div></strong></td> ";

                    foreach (var row in group)
                    {
                        sbodyMail += "<tr>" +
                            "<td style='width: 30px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["SR_No"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["userName"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["Document_Type"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["CountofDocNo"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "</tr>";
                    }



                    sbodyMail += "</table><br>" + //close of header

                        "<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";

                    string startupPath = "";
                    List<string> ls_attach1 = new List<string>();

                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

                    ls_attach1.Add(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls");
                    ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls", ds);

                    foreach (var attach in ls_attach1)
                    {
                        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attach));
                    }
                    foreach (Attachment attachments in mail.Attachments)
                    {
                        attachments.Dispose();
                    }

                    ce.SendEmail("nadeem.khan@powersoft.in", "", "", "Information on documents for processing", sbodyMail,
                                 "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach1, "ConnectionString");

                }
    }
```

Currently, each and every user is able to see all the data in the Excel sheet.

It should be like, the user can only be able to see it's own data only. For ex:

[image: JG]

For Ex: Chetan Mody should be able to see only two rows in excel sheet, but he is able to view all the records.

How do I do this?

Comment: Where do you make that selection? You make a GROUPING, but nowhere do you select what data you want to show with an explicit piece of code. Or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: I think so you are not filtering the data what you want from excel sheet.

Comment: As far as I can see, you just attach an excel-sheet without doing anything to it. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @J.Steen: sorry I missed that part of code, updated the question now. have a look

Comment: Doesn't really help - nowhere do you specify what the `ds` variable contains other than a (presumably) stored procedure named GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT. Then you push that into your excel-file without doing anything more to it.

Comment: @J.Steen: yes, what should I do in order to filter the data. So that only respective user can view their data

Comment: Oh, so there's no problem or error, you just haven't written the code yet?

Comment: @J.Steen: yes, there is no error. but need to filter the data while sending the attachment. Currently chetan mody can view all the data. have a look https://s31.postimg.org/mbqyr1ior/image.png

Comment: Does ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls", ds);actually save the data? so there is a physical file? you may want to swap the order of the attach and creation if it does

Comment: @BugFinder: yes it saves data. and there is physical file too but while sending it does not filter accordingly on the basis of RAName

Comment: No it wouldnt.. you told it to save ds. Not the filtered group

Comment: @BugFinder: then how should I make it filter and show it to the user any suggestion ?

Comment: @J.Steen: any suggestion or help how to make it work ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet adding which you will be able to filter the `DataSet`

```
You can use DataTable.Select: 
var strExpr = "username = Maya Vaidya AND Ref_no = 8G";
var strSort = "Ref_date";

 // Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
foundRows = ds.Table[0].Select(strExpr, strSort);
```

Above code can be applied to filter the dataset and the result can be used to create Excel which needs to be sent as attachment in the mail.

Update
1. First populate your main Dataset 
Now fire a query to get the filter values based on which you want to filter the main Dataset using below code

```
 using (SqlConnection sourceConnection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sourceConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM " +
            "dbo.Users group by user_Name;",
            sourceConnection);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
           //Get the record which you can use to filter the main Dataset 
           //apply the above code snippet shared to filter main Dataset.
           //Create Excel
           //Send Mail
        } 

    }
```

Comment: You want to filter the `DataSet` and the shared code will do the job. Your dataset will get filtered and contain only user specific data which you can convert into Excel and send as attachement. You can get the list of all Users and use them one by one to filter your dataset, with every filter , create Excel and Send as attachement.

Comment: but `"username = Maya Vaidya AND Ref_no = 8G";` this is hard code. I need to make it dynamic. how to do that. help me

Comment: You can fire another query to get the record before the dataset gets populated and get the details that you want to use as filter in the Dataset. Save the record returned by query in some collection. Now iterate through foreach loop. With every iteration filter the Main Dataset and get the relevant data, create excel and trigger the mail

Comment: May be can u help same thing with piece of code than it would be great. Coz I am unable to do this

Comment: Updated the answer. Update the query with the relevant fields you require to get which you want to use to filter main Dataset. `While` loop will help to iterate to all dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118513/discussion-between-stack-and-lara).

Comment: kindly don't post any code if you cant explain clearly what user wants. Thanks

Comment: People here are not to code for you. Don't expect as your employee who will do the job for you

Comment: I expected from you because you posted an answer, and u should justify your answer otherwise dont post the answer. I didn't begged to you for help. You posted the answer that's why I asked the doubt.